# sync log files to centralise server

Tags: logging

We are running aws auto scaling, and single application is running on many servers. And the major problem we are facing is to centralize log solution. We have tried many, but those are not up to the mark. Finally we are using https://www.fluentd.org/ ( td-agnet) since last 6 months, but sometimes it crashes when there is huge frequency of logs comings.

We also tried with some Java base centralized log solution, but it seems to take more CPU and more memory so we keep it aside.

So my requirement is clear as following.
1. If we could service with td-agent to making configuration changes to make it work with all big traffic.
Or
2. We have to go with some other centralize log solution which is open source, eating less CPU or memory.
Or
3. A paid tool which fulfills all the requirements.

I would also like to know, what you experts are using for centralizing logs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use "elasticsearch" (https://www.elastic.co/solutions/logging)  which is part of ELK stack for centralised logging.

Additionally, AWS also has managed service for "elasticsearch" named as Amazon Elasticsearch (AWS ES)